# Puppet Augeas Cannot set 'exclude' key value

Tags: puppet

I have a fresh installation of CentOS 6.9 on VirtualBox. I have installed puppet-agent 5.4 but receive an error when I apply the following manifest:

```
augeas { "yum_exclude_test":
  incl    => '/etc/yum.conf',
  lens    => 'Yum.lns',
  context => '/files/etc/yum.conf/main',
  changes => "set exclude 'dog cat'"
}
```

I have tried both the default /etc/yum.conf file, and a blank file. If I change the "exclude" key to "excludes" the file is updated correctly, but for the "excludes" key, the result is like so:

```
excludes=dog cat
```

Otherwise, however, I see:

```
Debug: Augeas[yum_exclude_test](provider=augeas): sending command 'set' with params ["/files/etc/yum.conf/main/exclude", "dog cat"]
Debug: Augeas[yum_exclude_test](provider=augeas): Put failed on one or more files, output from /augeas//error:
Debug: Augeas[yum_exclude_test](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/etc/yum.conf/error = put_failed
Debug: Augeas[yum_exclude_test](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/etc/yum.conf/error/path = /files/etc/yum.conf/files/etc/yum.conf/main
Debug: Augeas[yum_exclude_test](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/etc/yum.conf/error/lens = /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/share/augeas/lenses/dist/yum.aug:43.20-.35:
Debug: Augeas[yum_exclude_test](provider=augeas): /augeas/files/etc/yum.conf/error/message = Failed to match tree under /files/etc/yum.conf/main

 { "cachedir" = "/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever" }
 { "keepcache" = "0" }
 { "debuglevel" = "2" }
 { "logfile" = "/var/log/yum.log" }
 { "exactarch" = "1" }
 { "obsoletes" = "1" }
 { "gpgcheck" = "1" }
 { "plugins" = "1" }
 { "installonly_limit" = "5" }
 { "bugtracker_url" = "http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=19&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum" }
 { "distroverpkg" = "centos-release" }
 {  }
 { "#comment" = "This is the default, if you make this bigger yum won't see if the metadata" }
 { "#comment" = "is newer on the remote and so you'll "gain" the bandwidth of not having to" }
 { "#comment" = "download the new metadata and "pay" for it by yum not having correct" }
 { "#comment" = "information." }
 { "#comment" = "It is esp. important, to have correct metadata, for distributions like" }
 { "#comment" = "Fedora which don't keep old packages around. If you don't like this checking" }
 { "#comment" = "interupting your command line usage, it's much better to have something" }
 { "#comment" = "manually check the metadata once an hour (yum-updatesd will do this)." }
 { "#comment" = "metadata_expire=90m" }
 {  }
 { "#comment" = "PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo" }
 { "#comment" = "in /etc/yum.repos.d" }
 { "exclude" = "dog cat" }

 with pattern

 { /baseur((l[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]|[.0-9A-Z_a-km-z-])[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|baseu([.0-9A-Z_a-qs-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|base([.0-9A-Z_a-tv-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|bas([.0-9A-Z_a-df-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|ba([.0-9A-Z_a-rt-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|exclud((e[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]|[.0-9A-Z_a-df-z-])[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|exclu([.0-9A-Z_a-ce-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|excl([.0-9A-Z_a-tv-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|exc([.0-9A-Z_a-km-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|ex([.0-9A-Z_abd-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|gpgke((y[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]|[.0-9A-Z_a-xz-])[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|gpgk([.0-9A-Z_a-df-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|gpg([.0-9A-Z_a-jl-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|gp([.0-9A-Z_a-fh-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|(g[.0-9A-Z_a-oq-z-]|e[.0-9A-Z_a-wyz-]|b[.0-9A-Z_b-z-]|[A-Zacdfh-z][.0-9A-Z_a-z-])[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|g|e|b|[A-Zacdfh-z]/ = /((([^\t\n\r "#;](([^\n\r#;]+)*[^\t\n\r "#;])?)))?/ }
    | { /baseur((l[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]|[.0-9A-Z_a-km-z-])[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|baseu([.0-9A-Z_a-qs-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|base([.0-9A-Z_a-tv-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|bas([.0-9A-Z_a-df-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|ba([.0-9A-Z_a-rt-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|exclud((e[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]|[.0-9A-Z_a-df-z-])[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|exclu([.0-9A-Z_a-ce-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|excl([.0-9A-Z_a-tv-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|exc([.0-9A-Z_a-km-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|ex([.0-9A-Z_abd-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|gpgke((y[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]|[.0-9A-Z_a-xz-])[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|gpgk([.0-9A-Z_a-df-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|gpg([.0-9A-Z_a-jl-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|gp([.0-9A-Z_a-fh-z-][.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|)|(g[.0-9A-Z_a-oq-z-]|e[.0-9A-Z_a-wyz-]|b[.0-9A-Z_b-z-]|[A-Zacdfh-z][.0-9A-Z_a-z-])[.0-9A-Z_a-z-]*|g|e|b|[A-Zacdfh-z]/ = /([^\n\r"]*[#;]+[^\n\r"]*)/ }
    | { /#comment/ = /[^\t\n\r ].*[^\t\n\r ]|[^\t\n\r ]/ }
    | { })*

(the regex goes on for pages)

Debug: Augeas[yum_exclude_test](provider=augeas): Closed the augeas connection
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Augeas[yum_exclude_test]: Could not evaluate: Saving failed, see debug
Debug: Class[Main]: Resource is being skipped, unscheduling all events
Debug: Stage[main]: Resource is being skipped, unscheduling all events
```

Default yum.conf:

```
[root@centos-test ~]# cat /etc/yum.conf
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=19&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release

#  This is the default, if you make this bigger yum won't see if the metadata
# is newer on the remote and so you'll "gain" the bandwidth of not having to
# download the new metadata and "pay" for it by yum not having correct
# information.
#  It is esp. important, to have correct metadata, for distributions like
# Fedora which don't keep old packages around. If you don't like this checking
# interupting your command line usage, it's much better to have something
# manually check the metadata once an hour (yum-updatesd will do this).
# metadata_expire=90m

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify, what is the stray text `{ "exclude" = "dog cat" }`, also can you supply the actual content of the yum.conf that you are trying to edit.

Comment: The error is all from the puppet debug log, I have added further to the debug ouput, but there is too much regex to post. The yum file I am trying to edit is the default given in CentOS6, but even an empty file yields an error.